# Can I make Intellij Idea 11 IDE aware of assertEquals and other JUnit methods in Grails 2.0.x unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, ide, intellij-idea

I find it very odd that with such excellent Grails integration, Idea does not recognize standard JUnit assertion methods in Grails unit tests.  I created a brand new project and made one domain class with corresponding test to make sure it wasn't something weird with my larger project.  Even if I add a @Test annotation, the IDE does not see any assertion methods

```
@TestFor(SomeDomain)
class SomeDomainTests {

    @Test //thought adding this, not needed for Grails tests, would help but it doesn't
    void testSomething() {
       assertEquals("something", 1, 1);  //test runs fine, but IDE thinks this method and any similar ones don't exist
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact message Idea gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created an issue in IntelliJ bugtracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82790. It will be fixed in IDEA 11.1.0

As workaround you can add "import static org.junit.Assert.*" to imports.

Note: using "assert 1 == 1 : 'message'" is preferable than "assertEquals('message', 1, 1)" in groovy code.

Comment: adding "import static org.junit.Assert.*" to imports is a low touch workaround that doesn't seem to negatively affect any tests.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Idea has problems if you use 'def' to define a variable (so it's type is not known) and then you try to pass it to a Java method which is strongly typed. Because it can't infer the type.

So it will give a message with words to the effect of "there is no method assertEquals() that takes arguments with type String, null, null".

I wouldn't expect this message in the example you give (because you are using ints directly, not a dynamically-typed variable) but I thought you might have missed it when trying to create a simple example code snippet for the question.

Comment: On reading the question again I don't think this is the problem you are having. But will leave it here just in case (or it may help someone who finds your question).

Comment: Thanks, yes, that is not the problem I was having :)

Answer (score 0):

With the `@TestFor` annotation an AST will add methods to you test class and IDEA does not catch these methods.

You have two options:

1. Make the test class extends `GrailsUnitTestCase`.
2. Add dynamic method to your test class.
   [image: Add dynamic method to class]

Comment: Adding a dynamic method really defeats the purpose of what I want, which is IDE autocompletion.  It is a small help for future autocompletes of teh exact same signature.

Unfortunately extending GrailsUnitTestCase does not work for any 2.x style mocking.  As per the docs 'The new unit testing framework won't work with the old GrailsUnitTestCase class hierarchy. Your old tests will continue to work, but if you wish to use the new annotations, do not extend any of the *UnitTestCase classes.'